# RoR, Capistrano, Unicorn, Nginx, Cap deploy gives me 'bundle install' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, bundler, unicorn

I have runned cap deploy:setup & cap deploy:check, everything looks fine and dandy... However when I run cap deploy I get this error and don't know why it's there?

Error:

```
failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/deployer/apps/blog/releases/20121005162132 && bundle install --gemfile /home/deployer/apps/blog/releases/20121005162132/Gemfile --path /home/deployer/apps/blog/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'" on 192.168.1.121
```

deploy.rb

```
require "bundler/capistrano"

server "192.168.1.121", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :application, "blog"
set :user, "deployer"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false

set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "git@github.com:Preen/blog.git"
set :branch, "master"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup" # keep only the last 5 releases

namespace :deploy do
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
    end
  end

  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /usr/local/nginx/sites-enabled/#{application}"
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/unicorn_init.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application}"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put File.read("config/database.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end
  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config"

  task :symlink_config, roles: :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config"

  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision, roles: :web do
    unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
      puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
      puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
      exit
    end
  end
  before "deploy", "deploy:check_revision"
end
```

Comment: Bahh, I just realized that I've forgotten to install bundler on my server... Sorry for wasted your time.. Hope anyone else might have use of this...

Comment: Can you Post Your Answer below, and then select yours as the correct answer so that this stops showing up in Unanswered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install bundler on your server and it will work.